# WKWebKit takeSnapshot(with snapshotConfiguration:) not working on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, ios11, snapshot

Am I doing something wrong...?

On iOS, I am wanting to take a snapshot of a full web page. Until iOS 11, this previously wasn't possible without dealing with a whole bunch of logic to scroll the `WKWebView`'s `scrollView`, etc.

The following bug was reported to Webkit and fixed: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=161450

Resulting in this change: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/212929/webkit

Which now gives us a nice API on iOS 11 to take snapshot of `WKWebView`s content: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/2873260-takesnapshotwithconfiguration

This is all pretty great, except, I simply cannot get a snapshot when using this method on a device. When running the app in Simulator it work's great.

I've added two images below for comparison. Both are the images that are returned with `takeSnapshotWithConfiguration:completionHandler:`, however one is blank for the most part.

I've tried playing around with the web view's `frame`, the configuration, etc. but with no luck.

I am thinking that perhaps Simulator links against the macOS version of WebKit and somehow it works fine there. One issue, as well is that the `WKSnapshotConfiguration` header also doesn't appear to be exposed in Swift, so I had to add a bridging header that imports it.

Here's a sample project for anyone who's curious: https://github.com/runmad/WebKitSnapshotTest

[image: screenshots]

**UPDATE 10/20:**

So this fixes it but is a nasty hack:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    // webView.scrollView.contentSize == .zero initially, so put in a delay.
    // It still may be .zero, though. In that case we'll just call the
    // delegate method again.
    let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(300)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
        guard webView.scrollView.contentSize.height > 0 else {
            self.webView(webView, didFinish: navigation)
            return
        }
        // So this works... If you set the .frame of the webView
        // to that of the just loaded .scrollView and then load the
        // same URL again, the resulting .frame and .scrollView will
        // be the same size and the image render on a device will be
        // the correct size.
        guard self.hasLoadedOnce else {
            webView.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.width, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!))
            self.hasLoadedOnce = true
            return
        }
        webView.snapshotWebView(completionHandler: { (image, _) in
            self.updateWith(image)
        })
    }
}
```

So couple of issues:

1. (`asyncAfter` I knew of this one already and had that in there) Have to add a delay for the snapshot, since the `scrollView` still might be `.zero` for a little bit
2. Setting the size of the frame of the `WKWebView` to that of the correct `scrollView` size wasn’t working
3. Setting the frame and THEN RELOADING the `WKWebView` in what will be it’s true size works

**UPDATE 03/11:**

My radar (35094298) was duped today to [33812691](http://www.openradar.me/33812691) and closed, which means Apple is aware of the issue, at least.

Comment: Is this a question, or a bug report?  :-)

Comment: Question... Whether I have missed something entirely. I will be filing a radar if no solution can be found.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

Here's what worked for me (note: I used the extension from the sample project provided).

Inside the webView(didFinish navigation) I used JS to find the content width and height. I then set a global `rect` variable in order to pass it to `snapshot()` later in a button press. I could not get the `snapshot()` to work when included in the following code after the constraint is set.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    // To get the constraints properly set for preparation for the snapshot, the setup must be performed here.
    self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
        if complete != nil {
            self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                guard let contentHeight = height as? CGFloat else { print("Content height could not be obtained"); return }
                self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollWidth", completionHandler: { (width, error) in
                    let contentWidth = width as! CGFloat
                    self.rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
                    self.heightConstraint.constant = contentHeight

                    // Because it is known that the web page has completely loaded, it is safe to enable a snapshot to be taken
                    self.takeSnapButton.isEnabled = true
                })
            })
        }
    })
}
```

For me, taking a snapshot() had to be a new action, in my case, a separate button press. My conclusion is that the constraint needs to be set and the view reloaded in order for the content to properly resize.

```
    @IBAction func takeSnapButton(_ sender: Any) {
    // It is probably safe to assume that there is definitely an image at this point but to be extra 
    guard let image = self.webView.snapshot(of: self.rect) else { print("An image could not be taken"); return}
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to finish a major project before I learn Swift.  Would you please show your answer in objective-c?  I apologize for the imposition.

Comment: The method calls are the same. Thats all what matters